# Virtual Host directives on Server - should I change the .config files?

Tags: macos, server.app

I am trying to set up OpenPhoto on my Mavericks Server.

The instructions for a locally hosted site is to add directives to the virtual host config files.

Am I supposed to edit that file (0000_80_local_site.config)? It is written to by the Server app so am I afraid to edit it.

Where should I add the directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am battling with this issue as well. The Apple way of doing this is to create a web app and a plist file. The documentation is scarce, but you can type "man webapp.plist" at the terminal for an explanation. There is also an example app in "/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/webapps/com.example.mywebapp.plist" BTW,
I am looking at "Mountain Lion Server" and not the Mavericks version, so I am not sure if they are the same.

edit to add: I was able to get mine working by following the example at http://webapps.itcs.umich.edu/cosign/index.php/Mountain_lion_server_install

example app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"          "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>includeFiles</key>
<array>
             <string>/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/webapp_scripts/httpd_myinclude.conf</    string>
</array>
<key>launchKeys</key>
<array>
    <string>com.example.mywebapp</string>
</array>
<key>name</key>
<string>com.example.mywebapp</string>
<key>displayName</key>
<string>MyWebApp</string>
<key>proxies</key>
<dict>
    <key>/mywebapp</key>
    <dict>
        <key>keysAndValues</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>path</key>
        <string>/mywebapp</string>
        <key>urls</key>
        <array>
            <string>http://localhost:3000</string>
            <string>http://localhost:3001</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>requiredModuleNames</key>
<array>
    <string>mod_mystuff.so</string>
</array>
<key>requiredWebAppNames</key>
<array>
    <string>com.example.webapp.myotherwebapp</string>
</array>
<key>preflightCommand</key>
<string>/usr/local/bin/preflightmywebapp</string>
<key>startCommand</key>
<string>/usr/local/bin/startmywebapp</string>
<key>stopCommand</key>
<string>/usr/local/bin/stopmywebapp</string>
<key>installationIndicatorFilePath</key>
<string>/usr/local/bin/mywebapp</string>
<key>sslPolicy</key>
<integer>0</integer>
```

Looks like you would put your .conf file in "/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/webapp_scripts/httpd_myinclude.conf"